# Improper Integrals Problem

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Find the value of

$$\int_0^1(x \ln x)^3dx $$

Taking a substitute $x=e^{-y}$ i get the value as $$-3\over128$$

Does it look good ?

Comment: yeah that's right.

Comment: @Aman : have you used wolframalpha.com ? You can check your answer there.  They seem to accept any reasonble syntax, such as Maplese: int((x*ln(x))^3),x=0..1) would probably work.

Comment: @Aman: btw, I don't think it's really an improper integral, because $(x\ln x)^3 \to 0$ as $x \to 0^+$.

Comment: It is improper in the sense that x=0 is not in the domain of the given function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematica returns your answer too:

`In:= Integrate[(x Log[x])^3,{x,0,1}]`

`Out=-3/128`